# php "json?" decode issue

Tags: php, mysql, json

I got this from mysql, need help decoding...

```
[{\"label\":\"Text Field\",\"value\":\"\",\"identifier\":\"field20\",\"type\":\"customText\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Name\",\"value\":\"thisisafirstname\",\"identifier\":\"field3\",\"type\":\"oneLineText\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"50%\"},{\"label\":\"Name\",\"value\":\"thisisalastname\",\"identifier\":\"field39\",\"type\":\"oneLineText\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"50%\"},{\"label\":\"Phone Number\",\"value\":\"555-555-5555\",\"identifier\":\"field2\",\"type\":\"oneLineText\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Email\",\"value\":\"thisisanemail@examplemail.com\",\"identifier\":\"field4\",\"type\":\"email\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"How would you like to help?\",\"value\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\",\"6\",\"7\",\"8\",\"9\",\"10\",\"11\"],\"identifier\":\"field6\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"options\":[{\"value\":\"1\",\"show\":\"Project\"},{\"value\":\"2\",\"show\":\"Internship\"},{\"value\":\"3\",\"show\":\"Externship\"},{\"value\":\"4\",\"show\":\"Adviser\"},{\"value\":\"5\",\"show\":\"Judge\"},{\"value\":\"6\",\"show\":\"Council\"},{\"value\":\"7\",\"show\":\"Contribution\"},{\"value\":\"8\",\"show\":\"Speaker\"},{\"value\":\"9\",\"show\":\"Field Trip\"},{\"value\":\"10\",\"show\":\" Job Shadowing\"},{\"value\":\"11\",\"show\":\" Other\"}],\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Start of\",\"value\":\"15\\/07\\/2015\",\"identifier\":\"field33\",\"type\":\"datepicker\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"50%\"},{\"label\":\"End of\",\"value\":\"16\\/07\\/2015\",\"identifier\":\"field34\",\"type\":\"datepicker\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"50%\"},{\"label\":\"Who would you like to help?\",\"value\":\"3\",\"identifier\":\"field7\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"options\":[{\"value\":\"1\",\"show\":\"Entire County\"},{\"value\":\"2\",\"show\":\"Specific County Academies\"},{\"value\":\"3\",\"show\":\"Specific Schools\"}],\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"County Academy Styles\",\"value\":\"\",\"identifier\":\"field21\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"options\":[{\"value\":\"1\",\"show\":\"Business\"},{\"value\":\"2\",\"show\":\"Arts and Communication\"},{\"value\":\"3\",\"show\":\"Healthcare\"},{\"value\":\"4\",\"show\":\"STEM\"},{\"value\":\"5\",\"show\":\"Leadership, Law and Public Service\"}],\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Schools\",\"value\":\"4\",\"identifier\":\"field8\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"options\":[{\"value\":\"1\",\"show\":\"Berkmar\"},{\"value\":\"2\",\"show\":\"Central\"},{\"value\":\"3\",\"show\":\"Discovery\"},{\"value\":\"4\",\"show\":\"Lanier\"},{\"value\":\"5\",\"show\":\"Meadowcreek\"},{\"value\":\"6\",\"show\":\"Shiloh\"},{\"value\":\"7\",\"show\":\"South\"}],\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Berkmar\'s Academies\",\"value\":\"\",\"identifier\":\"field36\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"options\":[{\"value\":\"1\",\"show\":\"Science, Technology, Engineering & Mathematics (STEM)\"},{\"value\":\"2\",\"show\":\"Health and Human Services\"},{\"value\":\"3\",\"show\":\"Media, Arts & Communication\"},{\"value\":\"4\",\"show\":\"Free Enterprise and Leadership\"},{\"value\":\"5\",\"show\":\"Architecture & Construction\"}],\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Centeral\'s Academies\",\"value\":\"\",\"identifier\":\"field9\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"options\":[{\"value\":\"1\",\"show\":\"Business&Entrepreneurship\"},{\"value\":\"2\",\"show\":\"Fine Arts&Communication\"},{\"value\":\"3\",\"show\":\"Law, Education&Public Service\"},{\"value\":\"4\",\"show\":\"Medical&Health Care Sciences\"},{\"value\":\"5\",\"show\":\"STEM\"}],\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Discovery\'s Academies\",\"value\":\"\",\"identifier\":\"field37\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"options\":[{\"value\":\"1\",\"show\":\"Science, Technology, Engineering & Mathematics (STEM)\"},{\"value\":\"2\",\"show\":\"Health & Human Services\"},{\"value\":\"3\",\"show\":\"Media, Arts & Communication\"},{\"value\":\"4\",\"show\":\"Business Administration & Entrepreneurship\"}],\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Lanier\'s Academies\",\"value\":\"5\",\"identifier\":\"field10\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"options\":[{\"value\":\"1\",\"show\":\"Multimedia&Fine Arts\"},{\"value\":\"2\",\"show\":\"Public Service&Leadership\"},{\"value\":\"3\",\"show\":\"Life&Health Sciences\"},{\"value\":\"4\",\"show\":\"Global Business&Entrepreneurship\"},{\"value\":\"5\",\"show\":\"CDAT\"}],\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Meadowcreek\'s Academies\",\"value\":\"\",\"identifier\":\"field11\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"options\":[{\"value\":\"1\",\"show\":\"Communication&Arts\"},{\"value\":\"2\",\"show\":\"Information Technology\"},{\"value\":\"3\",\"show\":\"Health&Hospitality\"},{\"value\":\"4\",\"show\":\"International Business\"},{\"value\":\"5\",\"show\":\"STEM\"}],\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Shiloh\'s Academies\",\"value\":\"\",\"identifier\":\"field12\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"options\":[{\"value\":\"1\",\"show\":\"Arts, Media&Entertainment\"},{\"value\":\"2\",\"show\":\"Wellness, Health&Education\"},{\"value\":\"3\",\"show\":\"Marketing&Leadership\"},{\"value\":\"4\",\"show\":\"Science&Technology\"}],\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"South\'s Academies\",\"value\":\"\",\"identifier\":\"field13\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"options\":[{\"value\":\"1\",\"show\":\"Business&Entrepreneurship\"},{\"value\":\"2\",\"show\":\"Health&Human Services\"},{\"value\":\"3\",\"show\":\"Media Arts&Communications\"},{\"value\":\"4\",\"show\":\"Public Service, Law&Leadership\"},{\"value\":\"5\",\"show\":\"STEM\"}],\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Name\",\"value\":\"thisisacompanyname\",\"identifier\":\"field16\",\"type\":\"oneLineText\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Brief description\",\"value\":\"thisisabriefdescription\",\"identifier\":\"field17\",\"type\":\"textarea\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Who Referred You?\",\"value\":\"12\",\"identifier\":\"field40\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"options\":[{\"value\":\"1\",\"show\":\"John Tronolone (Berkmar)\"},{\"value\":\"2\",\"show\":\"Joshua Allen (Central)\"},{\"value\":\"3\",\"show\":\"Marlene Taylor-Crawford (Discovery)\"},{\"value\":\"4\",\"show\":\"Scott Allen (Discovery)\"},{\"value\":\"5\",\"show\":\"Kyle Jones (Lanier)\"},{\"value\":\"6\",\"show\":\"Diane Luong (Shiloh)\"},{\"value\":\"7\",\"show\":\"Elizabeth Schneider (Shiloh)\"},{\"value\":\"8\",\"show\":\"Tara Haynes (South)\"},{\"value\":\"9\",\"show\":\"Other (Berkmar)\"},{\"value\":\"10\",\"show\":\"Other (Central)\"},{\"value\":\"11\",\"show\":\"Other (Discovery)\"},{\"value\":\"12\",\"show\":\"Other (Lanier)\"},{\"value\":\"13\",\"show\":\"Other (Meadowcreek)\"},{\"value\":\"14\",\"show\":\"Other (Shiloh)\"},{\"value\":\"15\",\"show\":\"Other (South)\"},{\"value\":\"16\",\"show\":\"Other\"}],\"width\":\"100%\"},{\"label\":\"Captcha\",\"value\":\"\",\"identifier\":\"field28\",\"type\":\"reCaptcha\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"100%\"}]
```

This is what I did with the php

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: You should use `print_r($array)`. What other problems did you have?

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's not printing anything

Comment: Does the string really have backslashes before all the quotes? That isn't valid JSON.

Comment: that's invalid json.... you can try `stripslashes()`, but that could lead to other kinds of corruption if it removes backslashes that SHOULD be there. you need to fix whatever produced this bad json.

Comment: @Barmar That's why I put a question mark "json?" Because I'm not sure... I need help with decoding this

Comment: you have to remove escapes `\\`...

Comment: sometimes, MySQL breaks the apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone has said, this may break something else but try this:

```
$array = json_decode(stripslashes($json), true);
print_r($array);
```